elementor popup loads the external embed form each time u click
check this url when u click on book now button a popup appears on popup i am using external embed form whenever i click a form appears after some time when i click again it happens same and same. how can i resolve this issue
Note: i am not using elemntor pro form but external embed form
getchecked.health/cima-form-checker
I want that whenever i will open the form external embed form should not load
